# Can I declare an array in a if statement?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, if-statement

```
class Solution {
    public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {

      for (int i=0; i<= nums.length()-1;i++){

          for (int j =i+1 ; j <= nums.length()-2; j++){

              if((nums[i]+nums[j]) == target )
                  int [] r = {i , j};
                  return r;
          }
      }

    }
}

...
```

I wrote the following code but I am getting an error in my if statement. I am trying to solve a problem on leetcode but I am running into an error:

> Line 9: error: variable declaration not allowed here
>                     int [] r = {i , j};
>                            ^

What can I do to fix it and why am I running into this error?

Comment: I think it is because you missed a '{' after the if condition.

Comment: If you put in the braces, you *can* declare an array. The problem is that as soon as the block ends (as soon as the '}' is hit), the array goes out of bounds. So in this case it is useless.

Answer (score 1):

Formatting your code correctly:

```
if ((nums[i]+nums[j]) == target)
    int [] r = {i , j}; // only has scope during declaration
return r; // oops! r is out of scope
```

The compile error is caused by `r` not having any scope outside its declaration.

To fix, either:

```
if ((nums[i]+nums[j]) == target) {
    int [] r = {i , j};
    return r; 
}
```

or

```
if ((nums[i]+nums[j]) == target) {
    return new int[]{i , j};
}
```

Comment: It is caused by not using a block after the `if`. A block can contain declarations, but a single statement controlled by an `if` cannot.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can declare an array in an if statement.

But there needs to be more than just the array declaration.  In your code you just declare the array and do nothing else in the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

You must return something even if the value is not found.

```
class Solution { 
    public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
        for (int i=0; i<= nums.length - 1; i++){
            for (int j =i+1 ; j <= nums.length - 2; j++){
                if((nums[i]+nums[j]) == target ){
                    return new int[]{i , j};
                }
            }
        }
        return new int[0];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
class Solution {
public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {

  for (int i=0; i<= nums.length()-1;i++){

      for (int j =i+1 ; j <= nums.length()-2; j++){

          if((nums[i]+nums[j]) == target ){
              int [] r = {i , j};
              return r;
          }
      }
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to declare an array in if statement. But remember that the scope of the array is bound to that block of the if statement.
You can add '{' after the if statement and run it.

Answer (score -1):

1. The body of if block has to be a statement and the local variable declaration is not an option for the statement.
2. In this case, the java compiler knows that the array declaration statement will be unused as it is the single statement and there are no curly braces around. But if you write it in curly braces java compiler not surely mark it as unused and flag an error so it will allow you to run the code.
3. So write a declaration in curly braces.

Comment: (1) is correct. (2) is incorrect: the error isn't about anything being unused. (3) is correct.